# Save UIButton state NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I've a UIButton inside UITableViewCell. After a user touch on this button, I would like to disable it .
Here's the code that I use:

```
    class TextCell: UITableViewCell {
    var buttonstate:Bool = true
    [...]
```

-

```
      @IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
                self.likesButton.enabled = false
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(false, forKey: "buttonstate")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

and then:

```
     override func awakeFromNib() {

            var buttonstate: [String]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("buttonstate") as? [String]

            if((buttonstate) != nil){

                self.likesButton.enabled = false

            }
            else{
                self.likesButton.enabled = true

            }
}
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't work. (the buttons is stil enabled after a touch).
Thanks for your help and sorry for the question I just start,..

Comment: Maybe you need to also call `tableView.reloadData()` after updating your button state.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like below into your `awakeFromNib` function:

```
var buttonstate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("buttonstate") as Bool
self.likesButton.enabled = buttonstate
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Um, just for simplicity sake, can't the above be written as `self.likesButton.enabled = buttonState` ? What's with the extra if-else check ?

Comment: what is the issue now? @Mansour